# How to succinctly write all possible solutions of cosine when finding $x$-values at which a horizontal tangent to the curve occurs.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> For what values of $x$ does the graph of $f$ have a horizontal tangent?

Given $f(x)= x + 2\sin(x)$  then a horizontal tangent would occur when $f'(x)= 0$.

$$f'(x)= 1 + 2\cos(x)=0$$

Solving for $x$

$$1+2\cos(x) = 0$$

$$\cos(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x = \cos^{-1} -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

However, these are only the solutions over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. Due to the cyclical nature of cosine  its solutions repeat for every $n$ multiple of $2\pi$,  where $n$ is an integer. Therefore,

$$x = \frac{2\pi}{3} + 2\pi n$$
or
$$x = \frac{4\pi}{3} + 2\pi n$$

are all the possible solutions.

In my textbook, however, the answer is given as

$x = (2n + 1)\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$,  where $n$ is an integer.

I believe the book's answer is a more succinct way of writing the answer I got, but I don't know how to transition from my answer to the form the book has.

I recognize that $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is the reference angle to angles $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ which occur in quadrants II and III respectively, so I thought there might be some connection to reference angles and got the following:

For quadrant II:

$$\theta' = \pi - \theta$$

$$\frac{\pi}{3} = \pi - \theta$$

$$\theta = \pi - \frac{\pi}{3}$$

For quadrant III:

$$\theta' = \theta - \pi$$

$$\frac{\pi}{3} = \theta - \pi$$

$$\theta = \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}$$

But I'm unsure if this is the right track, or even if it was, how to get from my answer to the book's.

My two questions are:

1. How do I transition from my answer to the book's answer?
2. Is the book's answer equivalent to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2n\pi + \frac{4\pi}{3} = 2n\pi + \pi +\frac{\pi}{3} = (2n+1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$

and

$2n\pi + \frac{2\pi}{3} = 2n\pi  \pi -\frac{\pi}{3} = (2n+1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$

So,

> $x = (2n+1)\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$, $n\in \Bbb{Z}$